# using ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

I have my desktop in the office. When `X` starts, `ssh-agent` starts automatically. I have to add my `SSH key` once, at the beginning, and then I can use `ssh` without having to enter my password each time.

However, when I connect to my desktop via `SSH` (i.e. from home) the `ssh-agent` is not accessible and I have to provide my key every time. Also, even if I start a new instance of `ssh-agent`, I still cannot connect to it.

Is there a way to use `ssh-agent` on a remote system (to which I am connected via `ssh`?

Comment: Start your agent in your `.profile`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use agent forwarding: make sure to include `ForwardAgent yes` in your client-side configuration (`~/.ssh/config`), or use the `-A` command line option. (This feature can be disabled on the server side (`AllowAgentForwarding` in `sshd_config`), but this is only useful for restricted accounts that cannot run arbitrary shell commands.) This way, all the keys from your local machine are available in the remote session. Note that enabling agent forwarding on the client side has security implications: it gives the administrator of the remote machine access to your keys (for example, if you are at A and have a key for B and a key for C, and enable agent forwarding in your connection to B, then this lets B access your keys and hence log into C).

If you want to make the agent from your X session on the office machine available in the SSH sessions from home, then you need to set the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable to point to the same file as in the X session. It's easy enough to do manually:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXXXXXXX/agent.12345
```

where `XXXXXXXXXXXX` is a random string and `12345` is the PID of the agent process. You can automate this easily if there is a single running agent (`find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -user $USER -name 'ssh-*'`) but detecting which agent you want if there are several is more complicated.

You can extract the value of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` from a running process. For example, on Linux, if your window manager is Metacity (the default Gnome window manager):

```
env=$(grep -z '^SSH_AUTH_SOCK=' /proc/$(pidof -s metacity)/environ')
if [ -n "$env" ]; then export "$env"; fi
```

Alternatively, you can configure your office machine to use a single SSH agent. If the agent is started automatically when you log in, then in most distributions, it won't be started if there is already a variable called `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in the environment. So add a definition of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to your `~/.profile` or `~/.pam_environment`, and manually start `ssh-agent` if it isn't already started in `.profile`:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/$HOSTNAME.agent
if [ -z "$(pgrep -U "$USER" ssh-agent)" ]; then
  ssh-agent >/dev/null
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

In your remote shell, can simply run:

```
ssh-agent bash
```

That way you get a new SSH agent instance and a new `bash` shell with the necessary environment variables set. When you leave the shell with `exit` or `logout`, the SSH agent quits as well.

If you have the same keys available in the device you're using directly, you can also use `ssh -A` to make the *local* agent accessible to the newly started *remote shell*. It has some security implications but if you have the key available on both devices anyway, there's no difference.

When you want to connect to an existing agent, you need to set up the relevant environment variables just as they are set up in your graphical shell. It might be convenient to use an autostart facility of your GUI session to store the variables somewhere. You can get the environment variables using `env`.

```
env | grep SSH
```

For accessing the agent, you basically just need `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. The `SSH_AGENT_PID` is used to sending signals to the agent and other SSH variables are used for auxiliary tools.

You can also access environment of other processes via `/proc/*/environ`. The items are NUL-terminated not LF-terminated, though. I believe the file method is preferable in this case.

Comment: `ssh-agent bash` will basically start another instance of `ssh-agent`, correct?

Comment: @user1968963: Correct.

Comment: but I would like to connect to the `ssh-agent` that is already running.

Comment: @user1968963: That wasn't part of the question, was it? Will update.